# How to pass a object from a jsp to another using EL to get the object in the second jsp

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am passing an object from page1.jsp using

```
<form action="teste-altera-mvc.jsp" method="get"> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="${contato}" name="contato" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Alterar" />
</form>
```

Contato is my object with 4 properties. My problem is how can i get this object in "teste-altera-mvc.jsp" and display its properties using expression language

Comment: Consider using session attributes.

Comment: Don't do it. JSPs should not be used for any kind of processing. Servlet should process the object and return it to jsp if needed.